Thinkpad T490s Ubuntu 24.04 LTS: No sound output from speakers
When trying to play audio out of the device speakers no sound output is heard. Headphones plugged in to the 3.55mm jack works just fine. The computer is detecting the sound card and is displaying the sound "playing" but no audio is actually heard.
Tried a few different Googled solutions and still nothing. Tried reinstalling the alsa drivers and linux-audio drivers as well as some others.
Any advice / solutions?

Very often this is down to the volume being too low. I know it sounds silly, but there are various places where the volume can be controlled. First, double check (I imagine you have) the GUI settings and make sure nothing is muted or too low (run pavucontrol). Next, open a terminal and run alsamixer. Cycle through the options (F6 to get the list of sound cards) and check the volume of each and report back.

cutefisher's comment at: https://www.reddit.com/r/linuxaudio/comments/1d2i1rg/problem_with_sound_in_ubuntu_2404/ fixed my issue:

sudo nano /etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf
Enter this: options snd-hda-intel model=thinkpad
sudo alsa force-reload

